# The .find() function is running before .create(), even though it's below the .create() function in the JS code

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, frontend

I'm trying to follow along with Colt's Web Dev bootcamp and in his version, everything works fine but when I use the same code, a new entry is made into the database however it is not reflected in the printed items unless I re-run the code.

So, the question is, why is the .find running before the .create and is there a way to make it not do that?

The JS:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/catapp",
    {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
)
.then(() => console.log('Connected to DB!'))
.catch(error => console.log(error.message));

let catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    temperament: String
});

let Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

Cat.create ({
    name: "Snow White",
    age: 15,
    temperament: "Bland"
}, function(err, cat){
    if(err){
        console.log("error encountered");
    } else {
        console.log("new cat created")
    }
});

Cat.find({}, function(err, cats){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error encountered");
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("all cats found")
        console.log(cats);
    }
})
```

The terminal output is this (there might be many of the same entries because I've re-run the same program multiple times):

```
node cats.js
Connected to DB!
all cats found
[
  {
    _id: 5f4ea2d35e48bb06794bb96f,
    name: 'George',
    age: 11,
    temperament: 'Grouchy',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea30e0fa8f806bb79d164,
    name: 'George',
    age: 11,
    temperament: 'Grouchy',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea37dccb64207383a6d07,
    name: 'George',
    age: 11,
    temperament: 'Grouchy',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea515a1847108f841d71a,
    name: 'Snow White',
    age: 15,
    temperament: 'Bland',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea73d01e78f0ad300e5f7,
    name: 'Snow White',
    age: 15,
    temperament: 'Bland',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea7803b65d20b1d4206f7,
    name: 'Snow White',
    age: 15,
    temperament: 'Bland',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4ea9bab386320d1877eb0d,
    name: 'Snow White',
    age: 15,
    temperament: 'Bland',
    __v: 0
  }
]
new cat created
```

Comment: Just realized after posting, that it might not be clear since there are so many of the same entries, but the number of "Snow White" cats printed are one less than they should be (since the .find didnt include the one that was created at that very instant)

Comment: If you look at the form that `create` is taking, you are giving it a calback method.  That should throw the question into your mind that, "Is this method asynchronous?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and find are async.

Those functions will not always complete in the order they are called and the outcome will be determined by who completes first. This is known as a race condition.

To get around this, you will need to make sure the calls run in the correct order.

The simplest way is to put the `find` call into the callback of `create`. This gives you the added bonus of not running the find if for some reason creating the table fails.

There are 'better' ways of doing this depending on what you want to achieve, but that should be an exercise for you. You can read about async js, callbacks, promises, callback hell and the like to get started.

Answer (score 1):

`Cat.find` runs before `Cat.create()` because of the asynchronous nature of NodeJS.

You can use `Cat.find()` in callback function of `Cat.create` or you need to do it Promise-based.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be roughly written like this, using async/await:

```
try {
  await Cat.create ({
    name: "Snow White",
    age: 15,
    temperament: "Bland"
  });
  console.log("new cat created");

  const cats = await Cat.find({});
  console.log("all cats found")
  console.log(cats);
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Error encountered");
}
```

This would solve the order issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Cat.create` is an async function as by default most Node functions are, so before `Cat.create` completes `Cat.find` has already run.

Just put the `Cat.find` inside the callback method of `Cat.create` under the success if block then you should be good.